# What is the minimum hardware requirements for SQL Server Big Data Cluster?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, clustering

I am in process of making POC and would like to test SQL Server Big Data Cluster solution. My first idea is to host it on my local computer and test it but I am not sure If it possible. In found tutorial:

https://mohammaddarab.com/how-to-deploy-a-big-data-cluster-to-a-single-node-kubeadm-cluster/

is information that minimum hardware requirements are:

- 8 cpu
- 64 GB RAM
- 100 GB disk space

Do you know If it is mandatory (especially 64 GB ram) ?

Comment: 64 GB is also mentioned in Microsoft documentation. [Deploy with a bash script to a single node kubeadm cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deployment-script-single-node-kubeadm?view=sql-server-ver15).